# Cannot create R environment within Anaconda Navigator

Tags: installation, anaconda, rstudio

Within Anaconda Navigator I am facing a bug where I cannot select R when creating a new environment.

I am currently working on the IBM Data Science Coursera Certificate which requires me to use Anaconda Environment (normally I work in VS Code). We are tasked with creating a new Anaconda environment called "RP" where we select both Python and R packages as they are listed. However, the checkbox for the R package is grayed out and I am unable to select it.

I attempted using the Anaconda terminal and running "conda install r-rbokeh" but these are the results I receive:

Retrieving notices: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: |
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError:

How do I add R to my environment via Anaconda?